# Zurb Foundation 5 & Windows Phone 8: Site not always full screen

Tags: windows-phone-8, zurb-foundation, internet-explorer-10

We have been developing a mobile site using Zurb Foundation 5. It works almost perfectly, except for some unknown reason **Windows Phone 8 phones sometimes fail to render the site in full screen**. I say sometimes as in maybe 75% of the cases the site is shown correctly but about every fourth time it's not.

Here's a screenshot from Lumia 920 which shows the problem:

[image: IE 10 Zurb Foundation problem]

The problem gets fixed if the phone is rotated to landscape (and back to portrait).

We're using the following meta info on our site:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Also included is the following script in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
        var mq = "@@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}";
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mq));
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }
</script>
```

It feels like that the phone sometimes starts rendering the site too early. We have a splash screen with a centered progress ring and from that we can see that progress ring is at first usually on the left side of the screen (not full width) but it then gets centered (site goes full width). But sometimes the progress ring stays of the left and in these cases the site isn't rendered full screen. We haven't experienced this problem with Android or iPhone, only with Mobile IE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and and yet not solved in windows Phone 8 App. But when I upgraded same app to Windows Phone 8.1 the problem is solved. NO CSS and any JavaScript code is working like those link. Reason is in Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser Control is using IE 10 and in IE 10 there is a **BUG**. Microsoft tells that bug is fixed but it is not. This is bug in IE 10. In Windows Phone 8.1 Webview for Store App and WebBrowser for SilverLight App which use IE 11. Bug is fixed in IE 11 not in IE 10.
[Another Link for your Help](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/)
I have searched more than a week for same problem but I did not get any solution.

**If you got solution Please post here**

Thank You,